# Downgrade flutter package not similar to before the upgrade

Tags: flutter

Hello I tried to upgrade in_app_purchase 0.3.4+8 package, so that created some bugs due to somes changes. So I downgrade to return to a fonctionnal version but now it's not working... I only downgrade but it's like a modification in cache or other. How can I fix it ?

I try remove pubspeck.lock and flutter pub cache repair but no change

Thank tou

Comment: What bugs are you facing? Could you provide a stack trace if you have one and give us the code you are using with in_app_purchases

Comment: I use exactly the package example https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase/example

Comment: Before upgrade I had the button to purchase but now after downgrade It's like It's already purcahse, it display "v" icon